# Lenovo R61 : Possibly dead BIOS battery?

Tags: laptop

Sometimes when my main battery runs down to 0% and the laptop is without a charger for a while, the BIOS settings and clock reset.

Is there any way to confirm if this is a dead battery, or something else.

Also, if it is a dead battery, would a battery replacement suffice or will the motherboard need to be changed?

(laptop is under warranty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds exactly like the battery has gone. Testing the battery would require proper equipment, just replace it and see if it resolves the issue.

Page 87 of the service manual available [HERE](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/42x3547_04.pdf) tells you how to change the Backup Battery.

Just remove the main battery and then the palm rest to gain access to the backup battery. It may be worth calling the warranty provide and asking if this will invalidate anything. They may even just post you a battery and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to confirm is to replace the cmos (RTC) battery with a new one, I would contact Lenovo Warranty Support since it is under warranty, you would not want to void the warranty by doing repairs yourself.